# ASP.Net Textbox value lost during postback when you have a very large number of Textboxes on page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page where I dynamically create over 1000 textboxes. The initial creation and display of the page works fine, however when I do a posback I find that the control state (Text) is only restored for the first 997 textboxes. The Text proprty for all the other textboxes is not restored during the postback.

I am not seeing any errors - I just see that the textboxes are blank.

Has anyone else encounted this problem. Is there something special I need to do on a page that has a large number of controls or large viewstate ?

Here is some code to demonstrate.

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void CreateTextBoxes(bool load)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = string.Format("{0}", i);
            div.Controls.Add(txt);
            if (load)
                txt.Text = string.Format("Count {0}", i + 1);
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        CreateTextBoxes(!this.IsPostBack);
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen at the 998th textbox, can you put a breakpoint plz

Comment: I am not able to recreate the problem. I did have to add this to the web.config file in order to display a page with more than 1000 controls though  **<appSettings><add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000"></add></appSettings>**

Comment: Perfect that fixed it. Knew it was something like this but I just count not find the setting. thanks heaps.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following key to your web.config under the appSettings element if you have more than 1000 controls on a form, and set the value appropriately:
`<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000"></add>`

See this post for more details:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2012/01/16/using-an-http-module-to-assist-in-adjusting-the-value-of-aspnet-maxhttpcollectionkeys-imposed-by-ms11-100.aspx